# Why is python parser write me after avtorization that login or password wrong (output is in russian language)

Tags: python

I'm creating a new profile in a random site. Parser knows my data and must to log in in site but something is wrong and it's printing that login or password was wrong or unregistered person, how to fix that avtorization error?

```py
     import requests
     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     import fake_useragent

    session = requests.Session()  
    user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

    header = {'user-agent': user}

    link = "http://forum.ru-board.com/misc.cgi"

    data = {
        "inmembername": "<membername>",
        "inpassword": "<password>",
    }

    response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text  

    profile_info = "http://forum.ru-board.com/profile.cgi"
    profile_response = session.get(profile_info).text

    print(profile_response)
```

output:

````html
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
    <meta http-equiv="Set-Cookie" content="cookie=set; path=/"><meta name="description" 
    content="Компьютерный форум Ru.Board">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="Компьютерный форум Ru.Board">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="компьютер форум компьютеры программы">
    <meta http-equiv="Keywords" content="компьютер форум компьютеры программы">
    <meta name="Robots" content="index,follow"><meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no- 
    cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/board/board.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="Javascript" src="/board/Cheery/js/board.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" src="/board/AC_RunActiveContent.js"></script>
    <title>Ошибка :: Компьютерный форум Ru.Board</title>###general output
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Ru-Board" href="http://rss.ru- 
    board.com/rss.cgi" />
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffffff" alink="#333333" vlink="#333333" link="#333333" topmargin="2" 
    leftmargin="0">
    <table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 border=0 width="95%" align="center" bgcolor="#999999">
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td valign=top align=left class=tit><a href="board.cgi"><b>Компьютерный 
    форум Ru.Board</b></a> &raquo; Ошибка</td></tr></table>
    <br><table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 width=95% bgcolor=#999999 align=center>
    <tr><td bgcolor=#EEEEEE valign=middle align=center class=tit><b>Профиль</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor=#FFFFFF valign=middle class=dats>
    <br><ol  type=square>
    <li><b>Вы должны <a href='http://forum.ru-board.com/misc.cgi?action=login'>войти в форум</a>, 
    прежде чем заходить в свой профиль.</b>
    </ol><b>Возможные причины:</b>
    <ol type=square>
    <li>Неправильный пароль### general output
    <li>Неправильное имя пользователя### general output
    <li><a href="legal.cgi">Незарегистрированный</a> Пользователь              
                                                      ###general output
    </ol><br><center><a href="javascript:history.go(-1)"> << Вернуться 
    назад</a>
    ```
````

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is but... I definitely don't understand the comment about hacking your profile. Are you referring to your Stack Overflow profile? Or the profile on the site you linked to in your question? If the latter: You should *never* be providing credentials here, to an external site (I removed those credentials from your question). You can't control what people do with that information. As for your question: what, exactly, is your question? Please edit to provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

3 days [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILbaN.png)

```
data = {
"action":"dologin"### add this, becouse image
"inmembername": "login",
"inpassword": "password"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).